# How to run .sh script in Intellij in Windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, sh

I have a problem about running sh file in Intellij in Windows.

When I clicked the run button in the file, I got this output shown below.

```
PS C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\library> /bin/sh C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/library/aws-setup.sh
/bin/sh : The term '/bin/sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify t
hat the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ /bin/sh C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/library/aws-setup.sh
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/bin/sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Terminal | Shell path to `c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` or use Shell Script run configuration with Interpreter path set to `bash.exe`:

[image: bash]

Comment: I chose the Shell Script run configuration as above, but with unchecked "Execute in the terminal". Downside - can not work in the terminal after the command executed, but at least it was executed. :) Otherwise terminal had problems starting .sh file with git bash.